# How to parse json in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am receiving json string through an API from a website. However, the json format sent to me is not the format i want to work with. I want to change the received json string format to the desirable format.

This is the format i received:

> {"symbols_returned":147,"base":"USD","data":{"AED":
>   3.673010,"AFN":75.392000,"ALL":109.685000}}

This however is the format i desire to have:

> {"symbols_returned":147,"base":"USD","data":{"AED":"3.673010","AFN":"75.392000","ALL":"109.685000"}}

The difference between the former and latter is the presence of quotation marks on all the numeric currency values in the second json string. It can be seen that the first json string does not have quotes on the numeric currency values.

My question is how can i programmatically turn the first json string to the second json string format using dart programming language. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did u  parse the json ?

Comment: json['field'].toString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse the json data before you can use it.

you need to use the json package from dart:convert do do this

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

final yourResult = json.decode(API_RESULT);

print(yourResult) // {"symbols_returned":147,"base":"USD","data":{"AED":"3.673010","AFN":"75.392000","ALL":"109.685000"}}
```

will parse the json and preserve the data types  and make that a `Map`

Comment: please vote up and accept the answer if this solves your question

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. but json does not have "parse" as its method. This unfortunately did not solve the issue

Comment: @defemz i updated my answer, was a wrong method name

Comment: Thanks once again, the decode method did not do what i want, it removed all the quotations from the members inside the json. Like so: {symbols_returned: 147, base: USD , data :{ AED : 3.673010, AFN : 75.392000, ALL : 109.685000}}.

Comment: no it is what you want, its just how the print works, try doing this, `print(isNumeric(yourResult['symbols_returned])`